# How to convert coordinates of one SKNode to another SKNode?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uikit, sprite-kit

I figured out that if you want to use physics in Sprite Kit you have to specify anchor points in **world coordinates**. Say you have a big node tree and there is a car here and a wheel there. You know their coordinates in their parent nodes only. You want to define a spring joint between car and wheel but you have to tell Sprite Kit the anchors in coordinate space of your scene.

How would you then convert the spring anchor point on the car and the spring anchor point on the wheel center into world coordinates?

In UIKit there are conversion methods like `convertPoint:toWindow:` etc.
How do you do this in Sprite Kit?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [SKNode convertPoint:toNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/convertPoint%3afromNode%3a):.

```
[wheelNode convertPoint:CGPointMake(0,0) toNode:carNode];
[carNode convertPoint:CGPointMake(0,0) toNode:treeNode];
```

Something like that...